# Using Rails globbing for URL parameters: some URL types get cut off

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an odd problem with Ruby on Rails globbing. My route looks like this:

```rb
  get 'people/info_from_url/*url', to: 'people#info_from_url'
```

So from the frontend, I have get requests to URLs like:

- `my-api.com/people/info_from_url/youtube.com/XXX`
- `my-api.com/people/info_from_url/twitter.com/XXX`
- `my-api.com/people/info_from_url/tinyurl.com/XXX`
- ...

These all work as expected - I get a parameter in the `people#info_from_url` controller action called `url` that contains the full URL that was sent.

However, for one particular kind of URL (`XXX.carrd.co`), the last part gets cut off. In the frontend, I send a get request to `my-api.com/people/info_from_url/XXX.carrd.co`. From the backend logs:

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/people/info_from_url/XXX.carrd.co/"
INFO -- : Processing by PeopleController#info_from_url as
INFO -- :   Parameters: {"url"=>"XXX.carrd"}
```

Somewhere, the `.co` gets dropped. I'm not sure why this could be happening or how to debug it, since the change happens before I'm able to access the params hash. I could deal with this manually by just checking if it's a carrd link, but I'd like to know why it's happening and if any other kind of link might experience this issue. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes have an implicit optional `(.:format)` segment at the end. You can use this option to prevent that:

```rb
get 'people/info_from_url/*url', to: 'people#info_from_url', format: false
```

EDIT: you can check the last part here in the docs explaining that too https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you for the docs link as well!